# Cocoa framework integrated with GLUT and OpenGL

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am new to MAC OS X programming. I am trying to develop an application that represents the rotation movement of the earth in 3D. What I want to do (probably I have mixed concepts, so sorry me) is to develop a Cocoa app where I will can visualize some controls in the window.xib that will allow me to change the rotation speed of the earth and things like that. The big issue that I have here, is that I don't know how to "connect" this controls with a 3D sphere and his functionality. I wrote a C++ program that uses GLUT libraries, that represents the sphere and the rotation movement, but I think I am going in the wrong way. Please somebody can clarify me how to integrate GLUT with a Cocoa application and the controls that Coca framework provides? If this is not possible I will appreciate any guide, tutorial or advice to continue with the development of my app.
Thank you so much and sorry for my poor english.

Comment: They are mutually exclusive as GLUT provides a windowing system with event callbacks for things like keyboard and mouse interaction.  So does Cocoa.  You can probably keep much of your C++ code related to geometry and OpenGL, but you will need to rewrite anything related to window-setup and input events.  Apple will certainly have a sample app or two to get you started...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your basic options for Open GL and OS X are [Open GL](https://developer.apple.com/opengl/) or [GLKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKit_Collection/). GLKit is essentially an Objective-C wrapper around Open GL that integrates it into Cocoa.

My first suggestion however would be [Unity 3D](https://unity3d.com)

Also you can look into Objective-C++ if you really want to go down that route, however I'd advise against it.

Comment: OSX runs OpenGL not OpenGL ES.

Comment: My bad sorry. Fixed it. Too used to iOS!